# MySQL Database analyze problem in some table

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database

### Tables and relations

- Orders
- Products
- OrderItem

Relation between "Orders" and "Products" is many to many, and "OrderItem" table connects them.

### The Problem

When a product is ordered, the product has specific in-price, out-price, and discount. For example, Product A is added at in-price 100, out-price 120, and discount 0, and suppose later, admin changes one of these properties. Now, because the order has a reference to product A, there is a difference between the product details when it was ordered and the present.

I want the ability to be able to update product details. How we can solve this in relational databases.

Comment: It is common design for purchase orders and invoices to "capture and freeze" all relevant info at the time. Another option is to use product versions, or temporal design.

Comment: What do these mean: in-price, out-price?

Comment: @Rick 'in-price' aka purchase cost; 'out-price' aka customer price/sales price

Answer (score 1):

You need both.

1. In `Product`, which is the current value, that changes with a whim.
2. And in `OrderItem`, which is what the `Product` was actually sold for.
   This is not a duplicate.

```
Product (
    product-code,
    name,
    in-price,       -- current, changing
    out-price,
    )

OrderItem (  
    customer-code,  -- FK to Customer
    datetime,
    product-code,   -- FK to Product
    in-price,       -- actual, historic
    out-price,
    discount,
    quantity
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

When you promise a particular price to a customer, that goes with the customer `order` as, say, `promised_price`.  That is, you must (for business reasons) have a separate, potentially redundant, "price" to indicate this.

Then whatever the admin does to the in- and out-prices or discount does not impact promises already made.

If the price goes down (or up), you could *choose* to give the new price to a customer, but that must be a separate, deliberate, action to change the `promised_price`.

The overhead of having lots of prices floating around for each product is small enough not to worry about the space consumed.  *An approach like this helps you be an honest businessman, with auditable books.*